# Upload to OneDrive with Progress

Tags: swift, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm using MSGraphSDK to upload data to my onedrive using `uploadTask`. I want to use `uploadTask` because I want to show the user the progress complete. But I get the following error:

```
GET method must not have a body

Task <3A56385D-E93A-4A0B-A86B-510156030CBA>.<2> finished with error [-1103] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1103 "resource exceeds maximum size"
```

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    let testData = "this is a test upload".data(using: .utf8)
    let requestURL = self.graphClient.me().drive().root().item(byPath: "").requestURL
    
    let mutableUrlRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: requestURL!)
    
    let uploadSession = self.graphClient.me().drive().root().item(byPath: "foo.txt").contentRequest().uploadTask(with: mutableUrlRequest, from: testData, odobjectWithDictionary: nil, completionHandler: { foo, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error=\(error)")
            return
        }
        print("uploaded")
    })
    
    uploadSession?.execute()
    
    let _ = uploadSession?.progress.observe(\.fractionCompleted, changeHandler: { progress, _ in
        print("uploaded=\(progress)")
    })
}
```

How can I solve this?